# gcp bash script in cloud shell terminal

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I would like realized inventory of GCP API which are enabled in my organization, so I want to use bash script in my cloud shell terminal.
The code below works, but when I also want to organize result in array (with column Project and API), it doesn't work.
For example, when I put gcloud command in a bash variable, it doesn't work:
`services=gcloud services list --enabled --project $project`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for project in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
do
   echo "ProjectId:  $project"
   gcloud services list --enabled --project $project
done
```

Comment: Hey thomas, welcome to StackOverflow. What do you mean by it doesn't work? Do you have an error, or not the expected result?

Comment: Hello Guillaume, No error, but not expected output format. I would like "project ID" side of "gcloud services list" results, to work with excel later.

Comment: See also [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution with an additional nested loop

```
#!/bin/bash
  for project in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
       do
         for api in $(gcloud services list --enabled --project $project --format='value(NAME)')
           do
             echo "${project},${api}"
           done 
       done
```

It's a CSV format, it should be easy to read it with Excel afterward.

Comment: yes, works fine, thanks ! you just forget "--project $project" before "--format='value(NAME)')"

Comment: Correct, I added it. I tested on only one project ;)